# How to reorder columns systematically in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, select, dplyr

I have data that has information about each visit. Data is ordered in terms of each aspect, not each visit. I want to put together the columns including each visit information together. I provided sample data below.

I obtained what I desired somehow but, I want to see if there is a tidier way to get the same result. Here is what I tried.

```
library(tidyverse)

col_of_interest <- c("Total", "InstantDate", "VisitType")
col_orders <- paste0(col_of_interest, "_", rep(c(1:11), each = 3))

data %>%
    select(all_of(col_orders))
```

Here is sample data. You can ignore the `"NULL"`s and `NA`s in the data since I will deal with `"NULL"` somehow. `NA`s says that some people have up to 11 visit information but, some don't. Therefore, there are `NA`s.

```
data <- structure(list(Total_1 = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
"NULL"), Total_2 = c("17", "5", "3", "13", "NULL", "0"), Total_3 = c("15", 
"NULL", NA, "2", "6", NA), Total_4 = c("9", NA, NA, "8", NA, 
NA), Total_5 = c("15", NA, NA, "14", NA, NA), Total_6 = c("NULL", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Total_7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
Total_8 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Total_9 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_), Total_10 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), Total_11 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), InstantDate_1 = structure(c(18327, 
18330, 18332, 18332, 18332, 18333), class = "Date"), InstantDate_2 = structure(c(18673, 
18858, 18794, 18527, 18516, 18533), class = "Date"), InstantDate_3 = structure(c(18703, 
19044, NA, 18673, 18726, NA), class = "Date"), InstantDate_4 = structure(c(18786, 
NA, NA, 18905, NA, NA), class = "Date"), InstantDate_5 = structure(c(18855, 
NA, NA, 19006, NA, NA), class = "Date"), InstantDate_6 = structure(c(19229, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), InstantDate_7 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), 
InstantDate_8 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), InstantDate_9 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), 
InstantDate_10 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), InstantDate_11 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), 
VisitType_1 = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"
), VisitType_2 = c("FOLLOW UP", "FOLLOW UP", "VIRTUAL VISIT", 
"OFFICE VISIT", "NULL", "VIRTUAL VISIT"), VisitType_3 = c("FOLLOW UP", 
"FOLLOW UP", NA, "VIRTUAL VISIT", "VIRTUAL VISIT", NA), VisitType_4 = c("FOLLOW UP", 
NA, NA, "VIRTUAL VISIT", NA, NA), VisitType_5 = c("FOLLOW UP", 
NA, NA, "FOLLOW UP", NA, NA), VisitType_6 = c("FOLLOW UP", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), VisitType_7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), VisitType_8 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), VisitType_9 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_), VisitType_10 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), VisitType_11 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The point of my (since-deleted) answer is that it is **dynamic**, you don't have to hard-code things like `1:11` in your code. If this works for you, then keep it, there is no function I know of that "automatically intuits reordering columns by numbers and a non-lexicographic ordering of remaining strings".

Comment: You are right about mine which includes hard coding. I would suggest you keep your answer. Because the column names may not be as easy as this data always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may order on the numeric part of the column names and `select`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   select(order(readr::parse_number(names(.))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 33
  Total_1 InstantDate_1 VisitTy…¹ Total_2 InstantD…² Visit…³ Total_3 InstantD…⁴ Visit…⁵ Total_4 InstantD…⁶ Visit…⁷ Total_5 InstantD…⁸ Visit…⁹
  <chr>   <date>        <chr>     <chr>   <date>     <chr>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>  
1 NULL    2020-03-06    NULL      17      2021-02-15 FOLLOW… 15      2021-03-17 FOLLOW… 9       2021-06-08 FOLLOW… 15      2021-08-16 FOLLOW…
2 NULL    2020-03-09    NULL      5       2021-08-19 FOLLOW… NULL    2022-02-21 FOLLOW… <NA>    NA         <NA>    <NA>    NA         <NA>   
3 NULL    2020-03-11    NULL      3       2021-06-16 VIRTUA… <NA>    NA         <NA>    <NA>    NA         <NA>    <NA>    NA         <NA>   
4 NULL    2020-03-11    NULL      13      2020-09-22 OFFICE… 2       2021-02-15 VIRTUA… 8       2021-10-05 VIRTUA… 14      2022-01-14 FOLLOW…
5 NULL    2020-03-11    NULL      NULL    2020-09-11 NULL    6       2021-04-09 VIRTUA… <NA>    NA         <NA>    <NA>    NA         <NA>   
6 NULL    2020-03-12    NULL      0       2020-09-28 VIRTUA… <NA>    NA         <NA>    <NA>    NA         <NA>    <NA>    NA         <NA>   
# … with 18 more variables: Total_6 <chr>, InstantDate_6 <date>, VisitType_6 <chr>, Total_7 <chr>, InstantDate_7 <date>, VisitType_7 <chr>,
#   Total_8 <chr>, InstantDate_8 <date>, VisitType_8 <chr>, Total_9 <chr>, InstantDate_9 <date>, VisitType_9 <chr>, Total_10 <chr>,
#   InstantDate_10 <date>, VisitType_10 <chr>, Total_11 <chr>, InstantDate_11 <date>, VisitType_11 <chr>, and abbreviated variable names
#   ¹​VisitType_1, ²​InstantDate_2, ³​VisitType_2, ⁴​InstantDate_3, ⁵​VisitType_3, ⁶​InstantDate_4, ⁷​VisitType_4, ⁸​InstantDate_5, ⁹​VisitType_5
```

Comment: I tried this direct with `parse_number`  but used relocate instead of select(order)!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach building on @r2evans (since deleted) answer, specifically their use of `strcapture()`. It will group columns together by their suffix number, with columns sorted within suffixes by their first appearance in the dataset, without having to hard code column prefixes or suffixes.

```
col_orders <- strcapture("(.*)_(.*)", names(data), list(nm="", num=0L))
col_orders <- col_orders[order(col_orders$num),]
col_orders <- with(col_orders, paste(nm, num, sep = "_"))
data[col_orders]
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 33
  Total_1 InstantD…¹ Visit…² Total_2 InstantD…³ Visit…⁴ Total_3 InstantD…⁵ Visit…⁶
  <chr>   <date>     <chr>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>  
1 NULL    2020-03-06 NULL    17      2021-02-15 FOLLOW… 15      2021-03-17 FOLLOW…
2 NULL    2020-03-09 NULL    5       2021-08-19 FOLLOW… NULL    2022-02-21 FOLLOW…
3 NULL    2020-03-11 NULL    3       2021-06-16 VIRTUA… NA      NA         NA     
4 NULL    2020-03-11 NULL    13      2020-09-22 OFFICE… 2       2021-02-15 VIRTUA…
5 NULL    2020-03-11 NULL    NULL    2020-09-11 NULL    6       2021-04-09 VIRTUA…
6 NULL    2020-03-12 NULL    0       2020-09-28 VIRTUA… NA      NA         NA     
# … with 24 more variables: Total_4 <chr>, InstantDate_4 <date>,
#   VisitType_4 <chr>, Total_5 <chr>, InstantDate_5 <date>, VisitType_5 <chr>,
#   Total_6 <chr>, InstantDate_6 <date>, VisitType_6 <chr>, Total_7 <chr>,
#   InstantDate_7 <date>, VisitType_7 <chr>, Total_8 <chr>, InstantDate_8 <date>,
#   VisitType_8 <chr>, Total_9 <chr>, InstantDate_9 <date>, VisitType_9 <chr>,
#   Total_10 <chr>, InstantDate_10 <date>, VisitType_10 <chr>, Total_11 <chr>,
#   InstantDate_11 <date>, VisitType_11 <chr>, and abbreviated variable names …
```

Answer (score 3):

We could do it this way:

Notice: `values_transform = list(val = as.character))`

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = "key",
               values_to = "val", 
               values_transform = list(val = as.character)) %>% 
  arrange(parse_number(key)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = val, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

```
Total_1 InstantDate_1 Visit…¹ Total_2 Insta…² Visit…³ Total_3 Insta…⁴ Visit…⁵ Total_4 Insta…⁶ Visit…⁷ Total_5
  <chr>   <chr>         <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 NULL    2020-03-06    NULL    17      2021-0… FOLLOW… 15      2021-0… FOLLOW… 9       2021-0… FOLLOW… 15     
2 NULL    2020-03-09    NULL    5       2021-0… FOLLOW… NULL    2022-0… FOLLOW… NA      NA      NA      NA     
3 NULL    2020-03-11    NULL    3       2021-0… VIRTUA… NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
4 NULL    2020-03-11    NULL    13      2020-0… OFFICE… 2       2021-0… VIRTUA… 8       2021-1… VIRTUA… 14     
5 NULL    2020-03-11    NULL    NULL    2020-0… NULL    6       2021-0… VIRTUA… NA      NA      NA      NA     
6 NULL    2020-03-12    NULL    0       2020-0… VIRTUA… NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
# … with 20 more variables: InstantDate_5 <chr>, VisitType_5 <chr>, Total_6 <chr>, InstantDate_6 <chr>,
#   VisitType_6 <chr>, Total_7 <chr>, InstantDate_7 <chr>, VisitType_7 <chr>, Total_8 <chr>,
#   InstantDate_8 <chr>, VisitType_8 <chr>, Total_9 <chr>, InstantDate_9 <chr>, VisitType_9 <chr>,
#   Total_10 <chr>, InstantDate_10 <chr>, VisitType_10 <chr>, Total_11 <chr>, InstantDate_11 <chr>,
#   VisitType_11 <chr>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​VisitType_1, ²​InstantDate_2, ³​VisitType_2,
#   ⁴​InstantDate_3, ⁵​VisitType_3, ⁶​InstantDate_4, ⁷​VisitType_4
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```